# Why bootstrap accordion not displayed properly?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

Here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MichaelKut/68gk8/220/) where I implement accordion using angular-ui library 0.14.2 version:

The HTML view:

```
<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
    <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">        
        <accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">{{group.content}}</accordion-group>
    </accordion>
</div>
```

and it's works fine, But when I use implement it with angular-ui library 1.3.2 version  here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MichaelKut/68gk8/224/) accordion not display properly.

Any idea why accordion not display properly when I using newer angular-ui library?

Comment: Which error you face in 1.3.2 ?

Comment: I dont get any error

Comment: @PareshGami I updated my fiddlers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe it's because you're not using the correspondent tag's

```
<uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <uib-accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
      {{group.content}}
    </uib-accordion-group>
</uib-accordion>
```

here's a fiddle, you need a version of angular 1.4.x or superior to work with the angular-bootstrap 1.3.2. Also it required some dependency like `ngAnimate`

http://jsfiddle.net/68gk8/228/

Answer (score 1):

Paulo is correct - also angular ui 1.3.2 requires `angular 1.4.x` or higher.

Do this:

```
<uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
<uib-accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
  {{group.content}}
</uib-accordion-group>
```

and also update your version of angular accordingly.

Here is a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhsxdzqq/)